# Find and replace different columns using awk

Tags: awk, search, replace

I try to make a change in a file:

Find a certain value and substitute it with another value in a different column using `awk`.

**Input** (`UiO-66Zr-EH.mof`):

```
unit ntype qqatom
  1  'Zr1'  0.0d0
vibration
0
improper
0
unit ntype qqatom
  2  'H1'  0.0d0
vibration
0
improper
0
unit ntype qqatom
  3  'C25'  0.0d0
vibration
0
improper
0
unit ntype qqatom
  4  'O1'  0.0d0
```

**Output** (`output`):

```
unit ntype qqatom
  1  'Zr1'  2.222d0
vibration
0
improper
0
unit ntype qqatom
  2  'H1'  3.333d0
vibration
0
improper
0
unit ntype qqatom
  3  'C25'  7.456d0
vibration
0
improper
0
unit ntype qqatom
  4  'O1'  9.99d0
```

I've tried this command:

```
awk < UiO-66Zr-EH.mof '$2 ~ /Zr1/ {$3 ="2.222.d0"}1''$2 ~ /O1/ {$3 ="9.99d0"}1''$2 ~ /C25/ {$3 ="7.45d0"}1''$2 ~ /H1/ {$3 ="3.333d0"}1' > output
```

But it didn't function very well.

Can I do that with `awk`, while also keeping the same formation?

Comment: Could you explain what you need a little? How did your code fail? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: my command failed when encounters two similar strings ex: the C1 and the C13. What i am trying to do is to replace the values (0.0d0) in the qqatom column. That values are different regarding the ntype. ex: the Zr1 have charge of 2.222d0 and not 0.0d0. thancks :)

Comment: I have over simplified the example given. In my doc there are actually a C13 and C1

Comment: We can't help unless you show your exact file and desired output. Preferably by explaining in English what you need done. Also, please [edit] your question to add extra details, they are hard to read and easy to miss in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing a regex match on the second column, you probably just want to a string comparison. To do this with the example you have given, you have to include the single quotes in the comparison which turns the whole thing into a bit of a shell quoting nightmare. Doing that gives the following:

```
awk "\$2==\"'Zr1'\" { \$3=\"2.222.d0\" }
     \$2==\"'O1'\" { \$3=\"9.99d0\" }
     \$2==\"'C25'\" { \$3 =\"7.45d0\" }
     \$2==\"'H1'\" { \$3 =\"3.333d0\" }
     { print }" <UiO-66Zr-EH.mof
```

Answer (score 2):

The first issue here is that your values are quoted. I suggest you simply remove the quotes with a `sed` command and then, if you really need them, put them back after you've processed the file with `awk`. Something like

```
sed "s/'//g" UiO-66Zr-EH.mof | awk '{$2=q $2 q}' q="'"
```

The trick above sets the variable `q` to `'` so `q $2 q` is equivalent to `'$2'`. Just an easy way to get `awk` to play nice with single quotes.

Based on your script, you seem to want to perform he following replacements:

```
$2 is   $3 should be
---------------------
Zr1     2.008.d0
O25     -1.179d0
O1      -0.582d0
C25     -0.121d0
C13     -0.002d0
C1      0.625d0
O29     -0.741d0
H1      0.127d0
H25     0.495d0
```

If so, I would do something like

```
$ sed "s/'//g" UiO-66Zr-EH.mof |
   awk 'BEGIN{
        c["Zr1"] = "2.008.d0";
        c["O25"] = "-1.179d0";
        c["O1"] = "-0.582d0";
        c["C25"] = "-0.121d0";
        c["C13"] = "-0.002d0";
        c["C1"] = "0.625d0";
        c["O29"] = "-0.741d0";
        c["H1"] = "0.127d0";
        c["H25"] = "0.495d0";
        }
    {if( $2 in c){$3=c[$2]; $2=q$2q}}1;' q="'"
```

#### Explanation

- The initial `sed` just removes all single quotes from the input file.
- The result of the sed is passed as input to `awk`
- The `BEGIN{}` block is executed before the file is read and an [associative array](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays) containing your mappings is set up.
- In the main program, I simply check whether `$2` is defined in the `c` array and if it is, I replace `$3` with the corresponding value from the array.
- The `$2=q$2q` just puts the single quotes back around `$2`.
- Finally, the `1;` prints the line.

The output when run on your example is:

```
unit ntype qqatom
1 'Zr1' 2.008.d0
vibration
0
improper
0
unit ntype qqatom
2 'H1' 0.127d0
vibration
0
improper
0
unit ntype qqatom
3 'C25' -0.121d0
vibration
0
improper
0
unit ntype qqatom
4 'O1' -0.582d0
```

Comment: Nice idea using the array.